# difference between java and azure stream analytics

Tags: java, azure, azure-stream-analytics

Sorry for the question but is there any difference between Java Streams and Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics?

I do see what are the benefits that azure stream analytics bring about but is there any difference? For example, Something that Azure Stream Analytics can do but not Java Streams.

I do also understand that Azure Stream Analytics can be used with Java..

Comment: To the people who vote to close it due to being primarily opinion based, please try to understand what is compared.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing apples to oranges. Java Streams is used for processing data in process much like .Net Linq. See [this blogpost](https://www.foreach.be/blog/java-and-net-comparing-streams-linq) for a comparison.

[Azure Stream Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/stream-analytics/) is a cloud service that lets you analyse a vast amount of incoming real-time data (like thousands of events from different IoT sensors) and apply transformations to that data while outputting it to a destination like a file or a reporting tool and much more.

You see any similarities? No? Well that's because you cannot compare them like that.

About Azure Stream Analytics being able to leverage Java: I don't know. It uses a language on its own to write a stream processing job. See [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835001.aspx).

The apache counterpart that supports Java would be Apache Storm or Spark (I am not that familiar with those products), see also [Azure Storm vs Azure Stream Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130025/azure-storm-vs-azure-stream-analytics)